# What is the probability that 3 randomly selected letters of the alphabet match any 3 of 5 letters randomly selected earlier?

Tags: probability

On each occasion (selection of 3, then selection of 5) the same letter of the alphabet cannot be selected more than once.

I am no mathematician but I arrived at the answer 1/260
(5/26 * 4/25 * 3/24)

Not sure this is correct though!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Where did your answer come from?  Hint:  how many $5$ letter draws are possible?  Given a choice of $3$, how many $5$ letter draws contain those three?

Comment: My approach was that there is a 5 in 26 chance of selecting one of the 5, followed by a 4 in 25 chance etc...  but as I said I’m no mathematician lol. Thanks for the hint, I’ll see if I can work that out

Comment: 65,780 combinations of 5 letters from 26.

Comment: Not sure how to calculate how many of these contain the choice of 3.

Comment: Your attempt would have been clearer had you written $\frac{5}{26} \cdot \frac{4}{25} \cdot \frac{3}{24} = \frac{1}{260}$.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the $5$-letter draw.

There are $\binom53=10$ $3$-letter combination that satisify the condition.

There are $\binom{26}{3}$ possible $3$-letter draws.

Therefore the probability is $\frac{10}{\binom{26}{3}}$, or equivalently, $\frac{5}{26}\times\frac{4}{25}\times\frac3{24}$

Comment: @N.F Taussig I was overcomplicating the problem.

Comment: Usually, the binomial coefficient is written $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$.   Otherwise, it looks good.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks!  Just to clarify, is 1 in 260 the correct odds of this outcome (sorry about terminology!)

Comment: @RJohnson  It is the correct probability.  [Odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) and [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) are not synonymous.

Comment: Thanks. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I fixed the binomial coefficient problem. Thank you.